# CI > Custom Base Controller cannot find Model

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, controller

I have this file structure:

- application

  - controllers

    - home.php
  - core

    - MY_Controller.php
  - models

    - users.php

These are the codes for each file:

**home.php**

```
class Home extends MY_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        echo "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

**MY_Controller.php**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    var $user_model = null;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->user_model = new Users();
    }
}
```

**users.php**

```
class Users extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

When I load the webpage on a browser, I get this error:

Fatal error: Class 'Users' not found in C:\%path%\application\core\MY_Controller.php on line 7.

Please help me make my custom base Controller to find my Model. Thank you!

**NOTE**:
The cases are as I have provided them (I heard there might be issues with case-sensitivities).

**EDIT**:
When I opened the log files, I found this.
ERROR - 2014-02-17 01:02:05 --> Severity: 8192  --> mysql_pconnect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead C:\%path%\system\database\drivers\mysql\mysql_driver.php 91

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I got it to work by either going in the config.php file and autoloading the model or by doing $this->load->model('Users');

Upper or lower case U seems to work.